# Don't save form data over https

Tags: html, forms, https, credit-card, form-data

I'd like to submit data in a form, over HTTPS, without allowing the browser to save it.

(credit card transactions)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mean autocomplete="off"? Or cookie data?

Comment: I don't want the browser to save information such as credit cards. So will auto complete not save it?

Comment: Autocomplete would stop it from giving a dropdown of values previously entered. Beyond that, its more of a browser setting. Check this out http://www.petefreitag.com/item/481.cfm

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following code:

```
< form id="login_form" action="login.php" method="post" autocomplete="off">
```