# How to clear the credentials for my site that are saved by browser?

Tags: javascript, php, authentication, authorization, browser-cache

I have a simple php login form. When I login to the site, Firefox remember my credentials which is very useful in many cases. However, in some cases e.g. when user clicked Logout, I want Firefox to forget these credentials. So next time when I turn on my PC and open the site, my login form should not be prefilled with my credentials.

Can I clear the credentials saved by Firefox (or any other browser) via JavaScript or server side code?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Don't save form data over https](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2504307/dont-save-form-data-over-https)

Comment: @JeremyJStarcher I had like to user Remember Me feature in certain cases. I just want to clear that saved data when I press some button. The question you mentioned doesn't answer this.

Comment: @Jeremy - I'm not sure this is a dup. For example, does OP want `autocomplete="on"` until the user logs out? At which point, he effectively wants `autocomplete="off"` and the browser to forget the saved credentials?